# Tuples from Postgres not getting extracted onto the webpage using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm trying to develop a simple blog app using rails 5.0.1 and Postgres 
The problem is that,although 3 tuples are stored in the db (I checked it), when I extract it using "@posts=Post.all "command, only 3 horizontal lines occur(I.e the 3 tuples are scanned but not displayed). 
The code :

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<h3> <%= post.title %></h3><hr/>
<p><%= post.body %></p>
<% end %>
```

The index view:[image]
The Postgres DB: [image]

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). What is your actual question?

Comment: can you show more scope and controller action

Comment: Controller action: def index @posts = Post.all end

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <h3><%= post.title %></h3>
  <p><%= post.body %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The same result. Nothing changed :'(